# Does Promise add the call backfunction to microtask queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, callback

I read some files about the microtask and macrotask queue. I know that the callback function of a resolved promise is added to the microtask, same as the other sync tasks. But the following code:

```
fetch=() => new Promise ((resolve) => resolve ({m: 121}))

function x() {
    let d = 3;
    fetch().then((data) => {
        d += data.m;
        console.log("b", d);
     });
    console.log("a", d);
 }

 x();
```

gives a result of

```
a 3
b 124
```

IAs I thought, since fetch here fetches a "local" file and it takes no time, so the callback function is immediately added to the microtask queue, and then  `console.log("a", d);` is added to the microtask queue. If so, the result should be

```
b 124
a 124
```

So what is the reason for the real result? Why the call back function is executed after  `console.log("a", d);`?

Comment: Why would `console.log("a", d)` be added to the microtask queue?

Comment: "*I know that the callback function of a resolved promise is added to the microtask, same as the other sync tasks.*" this sentence makes no sense - sync tasks aren't added to a queue. That's what makes them sync, while adding to a queue is part of what makes for an async task

Comment: Read about [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not a callback is added to the microtask queue or the callback queue has nothing to do with how long it takes to run. The `Promise` callbacks are always added to the microtask queue. Regardless of how long it takes. And,  the queue is cleared, after the call stack is empty. In your example, the function `x` has to complete execution before your `Promise` callback can run. So, `a` is logged first.

Read more about the event loop [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). But in a nutshell, browser API callbacks go in the callback queue, and higher priority callbacks like the `Promise` callbacks go in the microtask queue. The queues are cleared only after the call stack is empty.

This can lead to puzzling behaviors like the following code running forever since the call stack never becomes empty.

```
let flag = true;
setTimeout(() => flag = false, 200)
while (flag) console.log('hello')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! you mentioned callback queue, is it different from the microtask queue and the macrotask queue?

Comment: @kaiyuwei callback queue === macrotask queue